# Placement of text e.g. suptitle inside the frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, suptitle

So far i have placed my suptitles above the frame, like this:

[image]

How can i get the suptitles from **above** the frame **into the frame?**

So far i have a solution that just prints a text and sets it on the right position with computing xlim and ylim. However this is errorprone and if the text is different it just looks aweful. Is there a way to set the suplabel into the frame? Or just place text below the frame and centered?
it would be really convenient, if i did not need to know about the data that is displayed inside the frame.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your solution using `text` is also my go-to solution. However, you don't need to compute the position based on xlim and ylim. If you set `transform=ax.transAxes` the coordinates for positioning the text are taken as being relative to the axes bounding box (0,0 being the lower left corner). Like so:

```
data = range(1,10);
fig = figure()
for i in range(6):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,3,i)

    ax.text(.5,.9,'centered title',
        horizontalalignment='center',
        transform=ax.transAxes)

    ax.plot(data)
show()
```

[image: Plot showing text relative to axes bounding box.]

Hope that helps!

Comment: so if i supposedly wanted to add a b c d on the upper left edge of these plots, who were all different ranges, how would i do that?

Comment: @tarrasch In this case, you may want to use `(0.0,1.0)` for the coordinates (or something like `0.1,0.9` to allow for a bit of space), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482667/9655481) and the [examples in the matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)

Answer (score 40):

Have you considered [`axes.set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html)? You can also pass x and y coordinates as keyword arguments `ax.set_title("my title", x=0.5, y=0.6)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Or even `ax.title("my title", position=(0.5, 0.6))`

Comment: That would be `matplotlib.pyplot.title`, or `axis.set_title`.