# How to put text inside a box on a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I'd like to put a text inside a box on a matplotlib plot, but the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#placing-text-boxes) gives only example on how to put it in upper right corner (and choosing different corner is not exactly straightforward).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the code from [the example](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#placing-text-boxes):

```
# these are matplotlib.patch.Patch properties
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.5)

# place a text box in upper left in axes coords
ax.text(0.05, 0.95, textstr, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14,
    verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
```

**Matplotlib coordinates**

Using `transform=ax.transAxes` we can put elements inside a plot in using coordinate system in which point (0, 0) is lower left corner, (0, 1) upper left, (1, 1) upper right, and so on.

To be specific: if we put a text box using position (0, 0) a specific point called `anchor` will be placed in lower left corner. To change anchor you need to add two arguments to the function call:  `verticalalignment` (possible values:  `center`, `top`, `bottom`, `baseline`) and `horizontalalignment` (possible values: `center`, `right`, `left`).

So to put box in lower left corner, you need to put lower left corner of the box in the lower left corner of the figure:

```
# place a text box in lower left in axes coords
ax.text(0.05, 0.05, textstr, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14,
    verticalalignment='bottom', bbox=props)
```

Anyways here is the link to [ipython-notebook with example for all placements](https://gist.github.com/jbzdak/8183530).

Comment: You can also use `annotate` which makes a lot of this easier.