# Use data coords for x, axis coords for y for text annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

From the documentation:

> The default transform specifies that text is in data coords, alternatively, you can specify text in axis coords (0,0 is lower-left and 1,1 is upper-right). The example below places text in the center of the axes:
>
> ```
> >>> text(0.5, 0.5, 'matplotlib', horizontalalignment='center',
> ...      verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
> ```

Can I instead use **both** *data* and *axis* coords? For x and y respectively.

Example code:

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [random.randint(2,30) for _ in range(15)]
plt.violinplot(values, positions=[1])

# This might place the text outside the figure
plt.gca().text(1, 30, "Text")
# I would like to use axis coords for y instead of data coords. Example call
# would be something like this:
# text_mixed_coords(xdata=1, yaxis=0.9, "Text")

plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

Potential results:
[image: plot.png]
[image: plot.png]

See also:
[Putting text in top left corner of matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482588/putting-text-in-top-left-corner-of-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is known as a ["blended transformation"](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations)

you can create a blended transformation that uses the data coordinates for the x axis and axes coordinates for the y axis, like so:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
```

In your minimal example:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

values = [random.randint(2,30) for _ in range(15)]
ax.violinplot(values, positions=[1])

# the x coords of this transformation are data, and the
# y coord are axes
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(
    ax.transData, ax.transAxes)

ax.text(1, 0.9, "Text", transform=trans)

plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

[image]

Also worth noting this from the [matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations) which makes it a little easier in this particular case:

> Note:
>
> The blended transformations where x is in data coords and y in axes coordinates is so useful that we have helper methods to return the versions mpl uses internally for drawing ticks, ticklabels, etc. The methods are `matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xaxis_transform()` and `matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yaxis_transform()`. So in the example above, the call to `blended_transform_factory()` can be replaced by `get_xaxis_transform`:
>
> ```
> trans = ax.get_xaxis_transform()
> ```