# How do I fix text position with multiple subplots in python with changing axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, figure, axes

I'm trying to figure out how to fix the position of text in multiple subplots, where the x,y axes are changing. Below is a copy of my code. I've tried transforming the axes, but the code disappears altogether. I can't specify the values for x,y axes, because for some it becomes impossible to see the data.

```
 fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(30,11))
    #fig.suptitle('Basin ' + basin_number)
    fig.suptitle('OFFSET = 5  ' + files[f][21:-7], fontsize=20 )
    basin_name = files [f][21:-7]
    #lim = min(axs[0,0])
    #ylim = get(gca,'ylim')
    #linear reg, Qb-Qt vs Qb-Qf
    axs[0, 0].plot(XX,predict_mean_ci_low,'-',color='C0', label="95% Conf. Band for Slope")
    axs[0, 0].plot(XX,predict_mean_ci_upp,'-',color='C0')
    axs[0, 0].plot(XX,predict_ci_upp,'--',color='C8', label="95% Prediction Bands for response")
    axs[0, 0].plot(XX,predict_ci_low,'--',color='C8')
    axs[0, 0].plot(XX,YY,'.',color='C7')
    axs[0, 0].plot(XX,fittedvalues,color='C1')
    axs[0, 0].set_title('Linear Regression')
    axs[0, 0].set_xlabel(r'$Q_b-Q_t$')
    axs[0, 0].set_ylabel(r'$Q_b-Q_f$') 
    axs[0,0].legend(loc="upper left")
    axs[0,0].text(1,-1, 'slope = {:.2f}\nr² = {:.2f}'.format(float(spp),float(r22)), bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.5))
    #axs[0,0].format(xlabel=r'$(Q_b-Q_t)/(\mathrm{max}|Q_b-Q_f|)$')
    #transform=plt.gca().transAxes
    # Qb vs time
    axs[0, 1].plot(db.index,db.Qb, 'tab:orange')
    axs[0, 1].set_title('$Q_b$ vs time')
    axs[0, 1].set_xlabel('time')
    axs[0, 1].set_ylabel(r'$Q_b$')
    
    #Qt vs time 
    axs[1, 0].plot(db.index, db.Qt, 'tab:green')
    axs[1, 0].set_title(r'$Q_t$ vs time')
    axs[1, 0].set_xlabel('time')
    axs[1, 0].set_ylabel(r'$Q_t$')
    
    # Qf vs time 
    axs[1, 1].plot(db.index, db.Qf, 'tab:red')
    axs[1, 1].set_title(r'$Q_f$ vs time')
    axs[1, 1].set_xlabel('T=time')
    axs[1, 1].set_ylabel(r'$Q_f$')
    
    # dL/dt vs time 
    axs[0,2].plot(db.index, db.dLdt, 'tab:blue')
    axs[0,2].set_title(r'$dL/dt$ vs time')
    axs[0,2].set_xlabel('time')
    axs[0,2].set_ylabel(r'$dL/dt$')
    
    # Area vs time 
    axs[1,2].plot(db.index, db.A, 'tab:purple')
    axs[1,2].set_title('Area vs time')
    axs[1,2].set_xlabel('time')
    axs[1,2].set_ylabel('Area')
    
    plt.savefig('glacier_all_annual/OFFSET_5_basin_' + basin_name + '.png', format='png', dpi=150)
    plt.show()  
    
    plt.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94S8H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrEXc.png)

I've tried transforming axes, the text dissapears. I've tried setting parameters for x,y axes, but for some of our data it becomes too difficult to see.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "fixing the position"? What is your desired result? Your post would greatly benefit from a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample data input, so that others could easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting text in top left corner of matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482588/putting-text-in-top-left-corner-of-matplotlib-plot)

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. Why can't you specify the x and y coordinates? You should specify proper values.