# Position text box fixed in corner and correctly aligned

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

I'm trying to mimic the `legend` method in `matplotlib.pyplot` where one can use `loc='lower right'` to position the legend box *fixed and properly aligned* no matter the axis and the content of the box.

Using `text` is out since this requires the manual input of the coordinates and I'm after something automatic.

I've tried using [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) and it gets me half the way there, but it still won't work right.

This is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define some names and variables to go in the text box.
xn, yn, cod = 'r', 'p', 'abc'
prec = 2
ccl = [546.35642, 6785.35416]
ect = [12.5235, 13.643241]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlim(-1., 10.)
plt.ylim(-1., 1.)

# Generate text to write.
text1 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(xn, ccl[0],
    ect[0], c=cod, p=prec)
text2 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(yn, ccl[1],
    ect[1], c=cod, p=prec)
text = text1 + '\n' + text2

ax.annotate(text, xy=(0.75, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=10,
    bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8),
    horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom')

plt.savefig('annotate_test.png', dpi=150)
```

which results in:

[image]

This will correctly scale for changing axis limits, but the problem is that: 1- it will fail if the axis are set to `ax.set_aspect('equal')`:

[image]

and 2- it will fail if the text is too long (here I set `prec=5` in the MWE above):

[image]

How can I tell `matplotlib` to position the text box *always in the top right corner and align it properly* so it doesn't fall outside of the image (ie: what `loc` does in `legend`)?

Comment: A very similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045729/automatically-position-text-box-in-matplotlib).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty way is to use right and top aligned text and place it at a fixed offset in points from the axes corner:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define some names and variables to go in the text box.
xn, yn, cod = 'r', 'p', 'abc'
prec = 2
ccl = [546.35642, 6785.35416]
ect = [12.5235, 13.643241]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([-1, 10, -1, 1])

# Generate text to write.
text1 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(xn, ccl[0],
    ect[0], c=cod, p=prec)
text2 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(yn, ccl[1],
    ect[1], c=cod, p=prec)
text = text1 + '\n' + text2

ax.annotate(text, xy=(1, 1), xytext=(-15, -15), fontsize=10,
    xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
    bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8),
    horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Because we've specified top and right alignment, it works with your two edge cases:

[image]

[image]

---

The downside of this is that the text is right-aligned.  Ideally, you'd want the text alignment to be separate from the box alignment.  The `matplotlib.offsetbox` module has a number of methods to handle things like this.

If you want to mimic a legend box (down to the location codes), have a look at `matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText`.  (Note that you can adjust the padding, etc though the `pad` and `borderpad` kwargs: http://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox )

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.offsetbox as offsetbox

# Define some names and variables to go in the text box.
xn, yn, cod = 'r', 'p', 'abc'
prec = 5
ccl = [546.35642, 6785.35416]
ect = [12.5235, 13.643241]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([-1, 10, -1, 1])

# Generate text to write.
text1 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(xn, ccl[0],
    ect[0], c=cod, p=prec)
text2 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(yn, ccl[1],
    ect[1], c=cod, p=prec)
text = text1 + '\n' + text2

ob = offsetbox.AnchoredText(text, loc=1)
ax.add_artist(ob)

plt.show()
```

[image]

One downside to this is that adjusting the font and box parameters for the result is a bit counter-intuitive.  `AnchoredText` accepts a dictionary of font parameters as the `prop` kwarg.  The box can be adjusted after initialization through the `patch` attribute.  As a quick example:

```
ob = offsetbox.AnchoredText(text, loc=1,
                    prop=dict(color='white', size=20))
ob.patch.set(boxstyle='round', color='blue', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_artist(ob)
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful answer as usual Joe, one quick question regarding your last answer which seems to be the simplest: how do I pass arguments such as `fontsize` and `alpha` to `offsetbox` to control the size of the text and the transparency of the box?

Comment: It's not well documented, but `AnchoredText` takes a dict of font properties as the `prop` kwarg.  Therefore you could do something like `AnchoredText(..., prop=dict(color='red', alpha=0.5)` to control the text color and other properties.  The color and transparency of the box itself is easiest to control by adjusting `ob.patch` after it's created.  (For example, `ob.set(alpha=0.5, color='blue')`.)