# Smart automatic positioning of text box in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, plot-annotations

I'm following the recipe given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25773791/1391441) by Joe Kington to position a text box in a corner of a plot, using the `matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText()` module.

This works perfectly if I know where I want to position the text box, but what if I want the box to position itself so that it *overlaps the minimum possible fraction of the content plotted in the same figure*?

This needs to work as generally as possible, so assume I don't know a priori what the plotted content will be and how it is positioned within the figure.

I've looked at the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredOffsetbox) but there doesn't seem to be a `smart` option available. Location codes are:

```
'upper right'  : 1,
'upper left'   : 2,
'lower left'   : 3,
'lower right'  : 4,
'right'        : 5,
'center left'  : 6,
'center right' : 7,
'lower center' : 8,
'upper center' : 9,
'center'       : 10,
```

For example, in this case (MWE below):

[image]

a better position would be the top (or bottom) left corner, but since I fixed the position manually via `loc=1`, the text box overlaps the plotted content.

Is there some way to detect where in the figure there is more available empty space and position the box there?

---

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.offsetbox as offsetbox

# Define some names and variables to go in the text box.
xn, yn, cod = 'r', 'p', 'abc'
prec = 5
ccl = [546.35642, 6785.35416]
ect = [12.5235, 13.643241]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([0, 5, 0, 1])

import random
pointx = [3. + random.random() for i in xrange(1000)]
pointy = [random.random() for i in xrange(1000)]
plt.scatter(pointx , pointy)

# Generate text to write.
text1 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(xn, ccl[0],
    ect[0], c=cod, p=prec)
text2 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(yn, ccl[1],
    ect[1], c=cod, p=prec)
text = text1 + '\n' + text2

ob = offsetbox.AnchoredText(text, loc=1)
ax.add_artist(ob)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than 3 years later, here's the solution: instead of `offsetbox` simply use [plt.legend()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) and take advantage of it's ability to position the text box in the "best" location by default.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define some names and variables to go in the text box.
xn, yn, cod = 'r', 'p', 'abc'
prec = 5
ccl = [546.35642, 6785.35416]
ect = [12.5235, 13.643241]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([0, 5, 0, 1])

import random
pointx = [3. + random.random() for i in xrange(1000)]
pointy = [random.random() for i in xrange(1000)]
plt.scatter(pointx , pointy)

# Generate text to write.
text1 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(xn, ccl[0],
    ect[0], c=cod, p=prec)
text2 = "${}_{{t}} = {:.{p}f} \pm {:.{p}f}\; {c}$".format(yn, ccl[1],
    ect[1], c=cod, p=prec)
text = text1 + '\n' + text2

# Create an empty plot with the required text.
plt.plot([], label=text)
# Remove the handle from the legend box.
plt.legend(handlelength=0)

plt.show()
```