# Add text on matplotlib graph in the loc = "best" fashion (not in data coordinate)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to include text on a matplotlib graph in an "empty area" in the same fashion as `loc ="best"` for the legend location?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is for a specific location in the fashion of loc="upper left"

Comment: You're right. i already noticed and deleted the comment.

Comment: There seems to be no way to do it without specifying coordinates
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045729/automatically-position-text-box-in-matplotlib

Comment: Ok. Do you know a way to contact the devellopers of matplotlib to suggest this evolution for the versions to come?